# WordPress Illegal string offset Warning in Post Metabox

Tags: php, wordpress

My custom post type Add New Product page show this warning

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'e_added_img_count' in /home/jb1063/public_html/wp-content/themes/virtualshowroom/framework/admin/metabox.php on line 66

Here is my code with line no 66

```
           <div class="added_slider_img_wrapper">
                <?php
                $e_added_img_count = $mydata['e_added_img_count'];
                    for($i=1;$i<$e_added_img_count;$i++){
                        ?>
                            <div class="gallery_holder<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                <label style="float:left; margin: 5px 5px 0 0;">Image <?php echo $i+1; ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="e_gal<?php echo $i; ?>" name="e_gal<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $mydata['e_gal'.$i]; ?>" style="width: 550px; float:left; margin:0 5px;"/>
                                <input id="_btn" class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

**This is line no 66**

```
$e_added_img_count = $mydata['e_added_img_count'];
```

Please give me a solutions.. I search on full stackoverflow & google... I got many posts with same title but problem is not same. means code are not same. Please give me a solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `$mydata` variable is not an array. There fore using the `[]` accessor is illegal. You will need to find out why `$mydata` is not an array. This is due to the code generating the content of `$mydata`.

If you want to see the content of `$mydata` for debugging purposes do:

```
var_dump($mydata);
```